# What's a good way to store an array of integers (java) to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, android-studio

I've been looking at various solutions for my problem, but I can't find a definitive answer for my specific case, so wondered whether someone could advise me or point me in the right direction.

In my Android Studio app, I have a 2-dimensional array of ints (representing a grid of colours). Currently the maximum size of the grid is 250x250, but I may increase that in the future. I know the size of the grid in advance.

I want to store this array in a MySQL database.  I was imagining something like a comma-separated string ("1,2,3; 7,8,9", for instance), but then read about serialization and wondered whether that would be better. The more I read about it, though, the more I thought it might be overkill for what I'm doing.

I'll never need to access an individual element from the database - it will always be the entire grid loaded at once.

Any thoughts on what might be the most efficient approach?

Comment: Most efficient? It depends, but i think (in your specific case) storing the array as Comma-Sep-String sounds not **too** bad...Everything else will **maybe** result in much more code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go all in with performance and size, I suggest using the [BLOB](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob.html) type for your database entry. Then retrieve it using the Blob class with the getBytes method, wrap it in a ByteBuffer, convert it to an IntBuffer and read it back into an int array :).

```
Blob b = (mysql stuff from JDBC);
byte[] bytes = b.getBytes(0, b.length());
ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
IntBuffer ibuffer = ((ByteBuffer) bbuffer.rewind()).asIntBuffer();
int[] intArray = ibuffer.array();
```

Then access with:

```
intArray[y*gridWidth + x]
```

I'd post more links, but not enough reputation :( anyway, its all pretty straightforward if you google a bit.

Once again, this is only for if you want to be real efficient about it, and I'm sure smarter people than me can invent even crazier and faster solutions. You could even go further and store shorts or bytes instead of ints. But remember that **Premature optimization is the root of all evil**. You're best off picking the easiest solution now and change it only when it appears to be too slow, take too much data, etc.

EDIT: just saw I didn't explain how to actually store it, it's essentially the same process but backwards. I can add it to the answer if you want, just leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks to you and the others who have replied. I'm going to go with the comma-semicolon separated method for now, but I'll bear this one in mind and probably change to it in the future (once I sort out all the other things that aren't working!).  Thanks again for all the replies.

Comment: As per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html ---Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on disk rather than in memory because the MEMORY storage engine does not support those data types (see Section 9.4.4, “Internal Temporary Table Use in MySQL”). Use of disk incurs a performance penalty, so include BLOB or TEXT columns in the query result only if they are really needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your use case. For extensible design,You can add a new table. This will give freedom of adding many entries in readable format in future.This way you take benefits of datatype constraints (for e.g. only integers allowed)  from DB, Add additional attribute (columns) to your table, in future And you would need less parsing logic while reading from DB.